# ViewController Navigating

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have 4 `ViewControllers`, `startViewController` as the initial View Controller. This contains my intro. After its finish, it will `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];` into my `menuViewController`.

---

```
startViewController ------> menuViewController ------> C1ViewController
                                          \
                                           \ ------> ImportantViewController
```

---

In my `menuViewController` are buttons for the two `ViewController` like the above illustration. Also I presented them in the View with this: `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];` I return to`menuViewController` with this `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

What I wanted is to make the `ImportantViewController` to be the like the parent view or the mainVIew even if I go to other Views. What I need is when `ImportantViewController` is presented when I go to either `C1ViewController` or `menuViewController` it wont be deallocated, or its content there will still be retained.

Is it possible? And How?

I don't know much about what parent and child view controllers for so I dont know what to implement in my problem. Thank you.

BTW, Im using Storyboard.

Comment: Why not using a `UINavigationController` for this?

Comment: I'm not quite good in `UINavigationController` in terms of using it. And my buttons are not in toolbar, what I know is `UINavigationController` is for the views with toolbars, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the `ImportantViewController` the root view of a `UINavigationController`, you will present a `UINavigationController` instead of the ImportantViewController,

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:YourImportantViewControllerOBject];

//insted of presentModalViewControlle with YourImportantViewControllerOBject you do
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Now in ImportantViewController to present new view controller you will do the following

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourC1ViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Where should I start implementing the navigation controller, because I'm using storyboard. and Im kinda new to navigation controller, that in my basic knowledge of it is it needs to be presented with a toolbar.

Comment: You could do the navigation bar in storyboard http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/

Comment: Can my problem be done by not navigation controller? or this is only the right way of doing so?

Comment: Yes it could, but what you are explaining is standard navigation controller issue

Comment: Hi i have done your answer, but how to remove the navigation bar, because when I'm presenting the view it has a nab bar? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% on what you want to do, but if you use ARC, setting the ImportantViewController to __strong it will be retained for you. Why dont you make the ImportantViewController the parent by creating the needed view controllers programmatically in the ImprotantViewController.m?

```
// ImportantViewController.m
// non ARC
FirstChildViewController *firstChild = [[FirstChildViewController alloc] initWithNib@"FirstChildViewController" bundle:nil];

//set firstChild.view position here if needed. e.g. .center = CGPointMake(x,y);

//now add firstChild to the parent
[self addSubview:firstChild];
[firstChild release];
```

You can do the same with the second view or any number of views. I find this nicer than presenting the view controller. You can also add Core Animations to the children views and create a nice UI.

Did this answer your question? Maybe I didnt get exactly what you wanted. :)

Comment: I cant go to ImportantViewContoller unless a press a button in MenuViewController,so how and where to implement it and Im using storyboard too.

Comment: You want to go to ImportantViewController? You can Connect the views in the storyboard and then use the button as the trigger. I think this post does exactly what you need. (skip to step 5 if you have your other views dragged into the main stroyboard already) http://kurrytran.blogspot.se/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html

Comment: No,no, I present the View one by one up until ImportantViewController, then when ImportantViewController is presented when I go to other views, I want ImportantViewController to be still retained with its contents not being deallocated.

Comment: rootView presents 2ndView. 2ndView presents 3rdView. and so on until you are at ImportantViewController. ImportantViewController can have the 2 other views as children. Create them programmatically with initWithNib in the viewDidLoad of the ImportantViewController and add them as subviews like in my answer. You can use the .view.hidden = YES or NO on the viewControllers. So you could actually create the important view controller prgrammatically as well and use the .view.hidden = YES or NO after creating it. This will not dealloc the ImportantViewController. It will just hide or show it.

Comment: I linked you with a tutorial explaining how to use storyboards. It shows how to setup a number of viewcontrollers and connect them with buttons and segues.